# How to allow a user to choose what class to initialise

Tags: java

I have an `abstract class Foo`, which contains a function `a(Object o)`.
Depending on what implementation of `Foo` you use, `a(Object o)` is implemented slightly differently.

I want the user of the program to be able to determine what implementation of `Foo` is used (eg., `aFoo`,`bFoo`, `cFoo`, etc), but I want to cut down on my use of conditional logic so that I can add to my program more safely in the future.

I currently have an `Enum eBar` that holds the names of all the implementations of `Foo`, which the user can choose from, but I am unable to determine how to use that to initialise the class.

Comment: Create base object. Each of your other object should inherit from base object. Do all operation on base object class and when you need to check which class is used try to check with instanceof java keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the instance of Foo to use, or add a method creating the Foo to use, in each enum instance:

```
public enum FooType {
    A {
        @Override
        public Foo createFoo() {
            return new AFoo();
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        public Foo createFoo() {
            return new BFoo();
        }
    }

    public abstract Foo createFoo();
}
```

Then, once the user has chosen the type, all you need to do is

```
selectedFooType.createFoo().a(object);
```

Comment: @irishMTS If this answer solved your problem then please mark it as the correct answer (click the tick symbol beside the answer). Every post on stack overflow is supposed to be useful to future visitors and questions with accepted answers are likely to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @progy_rock, but I had to wait a while before StackOverflow would let me accept the answer, otherwise I would have done so straight away.

Answer (score 3):

[**EDIT**] You can do that using an `Enum` like below

```
 public enum FooType {

       FOO_A(aFoo::new),
       FOO_B(bFoo::new),
       FOO_C(cFoo::new);
      //add as much as you want here

       private final Supplier<Foo> fooSupp; //the aim of using a supplier is to create a new instance each time you call the create method as mentioned in the comment.

       FooType(final Supplier<Foo> fooSupp) {
          this.fooSupp = fooSupp;
       }

       public final Foo create(){
         return this.fooSupp.get();
       }
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
final Foo myFoo = FooType.FOO_A.create();
myFoo.o(Object);
```

Comment: This is great, but I think that the answer given by @JB Nizet is a little easier to understand. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: This way, the `create()` function doesn't create a new object, but only returns the same object on every call. Better use `Supplier<Foo>` and `FOO_A(aFoo::new)`.

Comment: I see, I'll make and edit to my answer and let's us hope he can use that java 8 feature (`Supplier`)